# SceneKit - displaying 2d view inside scene at (x, y, z)

Tags: ios, 2d, scenekit

I need to display some view with notification in my scene at given position. This notification should stay the same size, no matter what is the distance. But most important is that it should look like 2d object, no matter what rotation camera has. I don't know if I can actually insert some 2d object, this would be great. So far I'm experimenting with SCNNodes containing Box. I don't know how to make them always rotate towards camera (which rotates in every axis). I tried to use

```
let lookAt = SCNLookAtConstraint(target: self.cameraNode)
lookAt.gimbalLockEnabled = true
notificationNode.constraints = [lookAt]
```

This almost works, but nodes are all rotated in some random angle. Looks like UIView with rotation applied. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Put your 2-D object(s) on an `SCNPlane`. Make the plane node a child of your camera node. Position and rotate the plane as you like, then leave it alone. Anytime the camera moves or rotates, the plane will move and revolve with it always appearing the same.

Comment: That's not really what I need, I want this objects to stay in 3D world at given X,Y,Z, so that when I rotate camera objects are displayed like in 3D world, they can get to of the screen. But I need these objects to be facing towards camera, which is at (0,0,0). I was trying to use SCNLookAtConstraint, but I was having trouble with this working when objects were moved (they need to move with 1 second animation). I'm sure there is some method to calculate pivot for given position, so that node is facing towards camera, but I can't find it.

Comment: This method almost works, but there is a problem with it - when moving animation begins objects flips back to it's original rotation, because I'm removing constraint, and when animation is finished it flips back. I need this constraints to animate from old value to new, so it's fluid. Probably I need to use some other method, because this only works when I reset constraint's like this.
    `node.constraints = []`
    `node.runAction(SCNAction.moveTo(enuLocation, duration: 1), completionHandler: { `
        `node.constraints = [SCNLookAtConstraint(target: self.cameraNode)]`
            `})`

Answer (score 0):

Ok I know how to do it now. Create empty node without geometry, and add a new node with SCNLookAtConstraint. Then I can move this invisible node with animation, and subnode stays looking at camera.